# How to sort multidimensional arrays in PHP?

Tags: php

If I var_export I get

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'date' => 2017,
    'id' => 128343,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'date' => 1976,
    'id' => 128315,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'date' => 2006,
    'id' => 128310,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'date' => 1967,
    'id' => 128304,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'date' => 1938,
    'id' => 128295,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'date' => 1978,
    'id' => 128293,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'date' => 1997,
    'id' => 128157,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'date' => 2000,
    'id' => 128124,
  ),
```

**The dates are mixed up.** I am trying to sort those dates and keep the Ids attached to each date DESC in order then to loop again but ordered. I tried

```
function custom_sort_dt($a, $b) {
   return $a['date'] - $b['date'];
}
usort($dateOrdered, "custom_sort_dt");
```

But I still get wrong order.

```
// the following gives a date
$myDate = (int)get_post_meta($id, 'usp-custom-14', true);

// this attaches the Id and the date
$dateOrdered[] = array("date"=>$myDate, "id"=>$id);
```

Comment: @Emma updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `array_multisort`.

```
array_multisort($data, SORT_DESC, array_column($data, 'date'));
var_dump($data);
```

Note that this function operates on the original array. If you want a copy instead, build one before by

```
$copy = $data;
```

Comment: @Emma See edit, multisort even takes the `SORT_DESC` constant.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try reversing the comparison to sort in descending order:

```
return $b['date'] - $a['date'];
```

Comment: but look at the var export, the dates are mixed up, so it isn't about reverting the order

Comment: Interesting rob.m. Can you include the code that sorts and dumps the array?

Comment: Your question mentions `var_export` before `usort`. It doesn't seem you're doing that in the right order.